# Version Compatibility between spring-rabbit and com.rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm using below  rabbitmq dependency in my application.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now due to some critical vulnerability I have to upgrade both the dependency.

I can't upgrade `<artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>` because upgrade requires code change.

if I upgrade ***com.rabbitmq*** application build and deployment both are successful.

so now I can upgrade ***com.rabbitmq*** to higher verion(version should be greater than 4.8.0)

Is it okay to upgrade ***com.rabbitmq*** to higher version(> 4.8.0) when we have spring-rabbit 1.3.4.RELEASE?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely to work and certainly not supported; 1.3.4 is nearly 10 years old.

The last 1.x release was 1.7.14 over 2 years ago.

https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp#support

You should upgrade to a supported release ASAP.